# El significado de la expresión "fuera de foco"

Tags: modismos

Tengo aquí una canción, [*Persiana Americana*](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=81453), que fue cantada por uno de los grupos más importantes de la música latina Soda Stereo.  Aquí está la letra de la rola :

> Yo te prefiero
>   fuera de foco
>   inalcanzable
>   Yo te prefiero
>   irreversible
>   casi intocable

Mi pregunta es que significa la expresión *fuera de foco* en este contexto? Es un modismo argentino o universal? ¡Gracias Totales!

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de añadir un enlace a la letra completa de la canción. Los dos versos que incluyes dan poco contexto (lo cual es normal en poesía y música), pero otras partes de la canción hacen referencia a ser "un espía o espectador" que mira a través de  una persiana americana. La respuesta de @rzanchez tiene más sentido al contemplar "fuera de foco" en ese contexto: te espío a través de una persiana y pareces _fuera de foco_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando uno iba a un cine y la película se veía borrosa es porque estaba "fuera de foco". En la canción de Persiana Americana de Soda Stereo es un símil o metáfora.

Answer (score 7):

*Fuera de foco* es un término de óptica. Cuando un objeto está fuera de foco, su imagen se ve borrosa. Esto puede darse tanto en una fotografía como en la visión humana si por ejemplo se tiene un problema como la miopía. Este significado no es un modismo argentino sino que es común a todas las variantes del castellano.

Sabiendo el significado original de la expresión, interpretarlo dentro del contexto de la canción ya no depende del idioma. Una posible interpretación es la literal. La canción habla de un hombre que espía a una mujer a través de una persiana. *Te prefiero fuera de foco, inalcanzable* querría decir entonces que el hombre prefiere la visión borrosa de ella que obtiene a través de su persiana, antes que verla de más cerca y con la posibilidad de contacto físico.

Comment: +1, La explicación concuerda perfectamente con el sentido de la canción (esa referencia a la visión borrosa - te prefiero inalcanzable). Debo añadir que aunque _fuera de foco_ sea "común a todas las variantes del castellano" a veces se favorece _desenfocado_ (lo sé, para la canción no habría pegado ni con cola. Simplemente quería señalarlo sin parecer criticón... :-))